# Loop through all checked check boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, checkbox, foreach

I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have two web pages, the first page has a number of check boxes in a form and POSTS to the second page. Is there a way to pass all the values of the checked check boxes to the second page so that I can find out which check boxes where checked?

Comment: Without seeing code. I will say you can make a list of booleans. and pass that list to the second page. Then run through the list doing something if they are true.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could pass that information in the `POST`. I would recommend getting those check boxes into the `<form>` tag on the first form and then when you `POST` to the second form you can pull those values out using the `FormCollection` like this in the `Load` of the second form:

```
var element_name_value = Request.Form["element_name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the checkbox values from the first page in session variables or cookies, and in second page you can catch it easily.
for set the all check box value in page 1 you just loop like this:

```
foreach (Control ctl in form1.Controls)
 {
            if (ctl is CheckBox)
            {
                //check for checked or not and set a value in session or cookies.
            }
 }
```

or use `id`

```
form1.FindControl("id");
```

Comment: Hi Shree, thanks! This is the code on the first page - `code` @{ //return all roles
        string[] arrayGetAllRoles;
        arrayGetAllRoles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
        foreach (string strRoleName in arrayGetAllRoles){
            <input id="@strRoleName" name="@strRoleName"type="checkbox" />@strRoleName.ToString()<br /> ;
            Session["arrayGetAllRoles"] = arrayGetAllRoles;
        }
    } `code`